# Subtracting through Iterations of dynamically-created form rows and inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an app that logs meals and their nutrition information. At the top of the page, I want to have a running count of the users daily goal, and their remaining calories, protein, fats, and carbs. I currently have an input form with the ability to dynamically add rows and input more food items per meal, which appends to the food log at the bottom of the page.

**Problem:** I am unable to figure out how to subtract all possible dynamic inputs from the "Daily Goal" and display it next to the "Remaining" columns. The closest I can get is that it subtracts the final row values from the daily and displays.

Please see my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dailyCal = 2000;
  var dailyPro = 125;
  var dailyFat = 56;
  var dailyCar = 250;

  $("#calGoal").text("Calories: " + dailyCal);
  $("#proGoal").text("Protein: " + dailyPro + "g");
  $("#fatGoal").text("Fat: " + dailyFat + "g");
  $("#carGoal").text("Carbs: " + dailyCar + "g");

  // On Submit
  var count = 1;
  $("#submit").on("click", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var $header = $("<h5 class='text-left' style='font-weight: bold;'>Meal " + count++ + "</h5>");
    $("#meals").append($header);

    $(".food").each(function() {

      // Assigns all values from all inputs on all dynamic rows to variables
      var food = $(this).find(".col1").val().trim();
      var calories = $(this).find(".col2").val().trim();
      var protein = $(this).find(".col3").val().trim();
      var fat = $(this).find(".col4").val().trim();
      var carbs = $(this).find(".col5").val().trim();

      var calRem = 2000;
      var proRem = 125;
      var fatRem = 56;
      var carRem = 250;

      $("#calRem").text("Calories: " + (calRem - calories));
      $("#proRem").text("Protein: " + (proRem - protein) + "g");
      $("#fatRem").text("Fat: " + (fatRem - fat) + "g");
      $("#carRem").text("Carbs: " + (carRem - carbs) + "g");

      // Appends all variables to the ID 'meals'
      $("#meals").append("<tr class='row text-center'><td class='col-sm-3'>" + food + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + calories + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + protein + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + fat + "</td><td class='col-sm-2'>" + carbs + "</td><br>");

    });

    $("#foodName").val("");
    $("#calories").val("");
    $("#protein").val("");
    $("#fat").val("");
    $("#carbs").val("");

    $(".dynamic").val("");
    $(".dynamicRow").remove();

  });

  // Add Row Button
  var counter = 1;
  $("#addRow").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    newRow.addClass("row dynamicRow food");

    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control col1 dynamic" id="foodName' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control col2 dynamic" id="calories' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control col3 dynamic" id="protein' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control col4 dynamic" id="fat' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control col5 dynamic" id="carbs' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-sm-1 dynamic"><span id="clickFA"><i class="ibtnDel fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x trash"></span></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#inputTable").append(newRow);
    counter++;
  });

  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1;
  });

});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: url('../styles/img/gravel.png');
}


/* Navbar */

#navbar {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px;
}

#brand {
  background: rgb(10, 177, 93);
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#navBtn {
  background: black;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#goalCard {
  margin: 40px 0px 40px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  border: none;
}

#dailyGoal {
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#userForm {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  border: none;
}

.trash {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mealLog {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  border: none;
}

#logHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#title {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}

#submit {
  float: left;
}

#addRow {
  float: right;
}

#motto {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
}

#form {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px gray;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#addMeal {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px !important;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
  /* position: relative; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#footerSpan {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 56px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>BiteTracker</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Firebase JavaScript Link -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="brand"><i class="fas fa-cookie-bite"></i> BiteTracker</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./profile.html">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./signin.html">Sign-Out</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Site Body -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Remaining Card -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card col-sm-12" id="goalCard">
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul id="dailyGoal">
            <li class="col-sm-3">Your Daily Goals:</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2" id="calGoal"></li>
            <li class="col-sm-2" id="proGoal"></li>
            <li class="col-sm-2" id="fatGoal"></li>
            <li class="col-sm-2" id="carGoal"></li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="remaining">
            <li class="col-sm-3">Remaining:</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2" id="calRem">Calories: 2000</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2" id="proRem">Protein: 125g</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2" id="fatRem">Fat: 56g</li>
            <li class="col-sm-2" id="carRem">Carbs: 250g</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- User Meal Submit -->
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="card bg-light text-dark" id="userForm">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="text-center" id="addMeal">Add Meal</h2>
          <table id="inputTable" class="table order-list">
            <thead>
              <tr class="row text-center">
                <td class="col-sm-3">Food</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Calories</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Protein (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Fat (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">Carbs (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="row food" id="staticRow">
                <td class="col-sm-3">
                  <input type="text" id="foodName" name="foodName" class="col1 form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="calories" name="calories" class="col2 form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="protein" name="protein" class="col3 form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="fat" name="fat" class="col4 form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-2">
                  <input type="text" id="carbs" name="carbs" class="col5 form-control" />
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="addRow" value="Add Row">Add
                        Row</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Meal Log -->
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="card col-sm-12 bg-light text-dark" id="mealLog">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="text-center" id="logHeader">Meal Log</h2>
          <table id="logTable" class="table order-list text-center">
            <thead>
              <tr class="row text-center">
                <td class="col-sm-3" id="foodEntry">Food</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="caloriesEntry">Calories</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="proteinEntry">Protein (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="fatEntry">Fat (g)</td>
                <td class="col-sm-2" id="carbsEntry">Carbs (g)</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="meals">
              <td></td>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="footer bg-dark text-light">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      <span id="footerSpan">BiteTracker &copy; 2018</span>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="../public/js/firebase.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: I'd think you'd just recalculate the entire table rather than subtracting. Also, you seem to be appending ID values repeatedly. You'll want to add an incremented index to them, or something, to keep them unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining your `calRem` variables inside of the `.each` loop. Define them at the top next to your daily goal variables. That way they don't get reset for each item in the loop.

Then as you loop through you just use `calRem = calRem - current_item_value` to keep track of the remaining amount.

**Edit:**

Thanks to closures in Javascript, a variable defined in a function is accessible by all functions that are children of the parent. The benefit here is that you define the variables once, give them a value, and the code can access those values while within that parent function allowing you to call it from within your loops.

When you do call it two things happen:

1) The variables are still 'within scope' so they are accessible (otherwise you'd see 'undefined')
2) The values can be accessed/changed from multiple child functions

Comment: Not sure what you mean by current_item_value. Would that be the calories variable in the loop?

Comment: Yes, the value you are trying to subtract from your remaining subtotal.

Comment: No problem, please see my edit for more information on why it worked.